# Why when 127*2 the result is -2 when we change to byte?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte a=(byte)127, b=2;    
    byte c=(byte)(a*b);

    System.out.println(c);
  }    
}
```

Why is the result `-2`?

Comment: A byte is only eight bits long.

Comment: byte over flow and two's complement goes to negative number

Comment: Are you aware that your (64-bit?) CPU will have a hard time fiddling around with bytes?

Comment: See also: [Why does ~True result in -2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881362)

Answer (score 9):

Because `a*b` will result in a temporary *int* variable, namely, 254, which is 1111 1110. When cast to byte, this will be handled as a *signed* value. The MSB is 1, so its value will be negative, and the value will be -(((inv)111 1110) + 1) = -((000 0001) + 1) = -2.

Answer (score 3):

`a * b` is 254, so your code is:

`byte c=(byte)254;`

The decimal 254 is the binary **11111110**, which is: -2. Why?

First of all, the number is negative since it begins with 1 (Two's complement), then:

`¬ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0` is `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1`.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
              1 +
---------------
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

This represents 2 in decimal, but remember that the [MSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) is 1? So final result is **-2**.

Answer (score 0):

Since byte is a signed type 2 * 127 is binary "11111110", which is [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for -2.

Answer (score 0):

because byte is signed, not unsigned.

> 254 = FE = 1111 1110

the first `'1'` represent the number as a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

127 in 8 bits is represented in binary like this:

```
01111111
```

Multiply by 2, and you get this:

```
11111110
```

(When you multiply by 10 in base 10, all the digits can be shifted left, to the next position. The same is naturally true when you multiply by 2 in binary)

Java uses 2's complement to represent negative numbers. Basically, the left-most bit is the sign bit (0 for +, 1 for -). To convert a positive number in a negative number, flip all the bits and add one.

Example: `00000010` = 2, flip the bits: `11111101`, then add one: `11111110` = -2. This is the same as 127*2 above.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you tried to ask is why overflow of a 8bits signed integer will turned to negative number for your case.
As in CPU, there is not a 8bits ALU, so 8bits will be expand to 32bits, after operation, return the lower 8bits to user.
In CPU: `0000_007F * 0000_0002 = 0000_00FE`
This is a overflow for signed 8bits, but the value has been calculated already.
So returned value is `FE`.
For 8bits signed, `FE` is `-2`.