# Why does ~True result in -2?

Tags: python, data-conversion, tilde

In Python console:

```
~True
```

Gives me:

```
-2
```

Why? Can someone explain this particular case to me in binary?

Comment: because `~1` is `-2`, Try: `True == 1`

Comment: Just to be precise: it is not true that "`True is 1`", but is is true that `True == 1`.

Comment: Do you really think seeing `UNARY_INVERT` (the whole of the bytecode) will add anything to answers?

Comment: This question is **not** a duplicate! It asks about a specific behaviour of `bool`. It's not about how `~` works. In fact a valid answer to this question could avoid mentioning 2's complement and how `~` operates on integers at all.

Comment: See also: [Why when 127*2 the result is -2 when we change to byte?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785792)

Answer (score 244, accepted):

`int(True)` is `1`.

`1` is:

```
00000001
```

and `~1` is:

```
11111110
```

Which is `-2` in [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Flip all the bits, add 1 to the resulting number and interpret the result as a *binary representation* of the magnitude and add a negative sign (since the number begins with 1):

```
11111110 → 00000001 → 00000010 
         ↑          ↑ 
       Flip       Add 1
```

Which is 2, but the sign is negative since the [MSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) is 1.

---

Worth mentioning:

Think about `bool`, you'll find that it's numeric in nature - It has two values, `True` and `False`, and they are just "customized" versions of the integers 1 and 0 that only print themselves differently. They are *subclasses* of the integer type `int`.

So they behave exactly as 1 and 0, except that `bool` redefines `str` and `repr` to display them differently.

```
>>> type(True)
<class 'bool'>
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True

>>> True == 1
True
>>> True is 1  # they're still different objects
False
```

Comment: @ofcapl Just wanted to say: Although `int('1')` is also `1` but `~'1'` be a typeerror exception whereas `~True` is not this is because `bool` is a subclass of `int` @ Martijn added this information in his answer.

Comment: For the record, @ofcapl, this answer shows the binary arithmetic interpretation of what's going on, not the actual [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) (which would be some sort of intermediate or operation level code compiled from the source).

Comment: Why is True=1 instead of -1, as it is in virtually every other language? (Sorry, PEP Index is currently out of service)

Comment: @etrusco what languages are you talking about? I know exactly 0 where `True == -1`, and I know many where one could say that `True == 1`...

Comment: @etrusco @l4mpi Some old-school BASICs use `-1` for TRUE; it has the nice property that the bitwise AND and OR operators work for logical AND and OR as well (`x & -1` is non-zero in the same cases that `x && 1` is non-zero in C), as long as you don't care about short-circuiting. However, as far as I know, no mainstream language has ever used `-1` for TRUE.

Comment: Formal logic defines `truth` as univalued; with all that is not `true` being `false`. All programming languages that I'm aware of turn formal logic on its head, defining `false` as univalued (0) and all that is not false being `true`). For instance [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0b8dwce(v=vs.110).aspx), though Javascript is something of an outlier, having multiple flavors of truthiness and [multiple flavors of falsiness](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html).

Answer (score 45):

The Python `bool` type is a subclass of `int` (for historical reasons; booleans were only added in Python 2.3).

Since `int(True)` is `1`, `~True` is `~1` is `-2`.

See [PEP 285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) for why `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

If you wanted the boolean inverse, use `not`:

```
>>> not True
False
>>> not False
True
```

If you wanted to know why `~1` is `-2`, it's because you are inverting all bits in a signed integer; `00000001` becomes `1111110` which in a *signed* integer is a negative number, see [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

```
>>> # Python 3
...
>>> import struct
>>> format(struct.pack('b', 1)[0], '08b')
'00000001'
>>> format(struct.pack('b', ~1)[0], '08b')
'11111110'
```

where the initial `1` bit means the value is negative, and the rest of the bits encode the inverse of the positive number minus one.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: For two's compliment, you could use `struct.pack`, as `bin(integer)` or `format(integer, '08b')` don't take signed integers into account.

Comment: @thefourtheye , MartijnPieters I Tried But it is confusing e.g. `bin(~True)`,  `bin(-2)`, `bin(~1)` all gives `'-0b10'`  If `-2` representation is `10` then why `-` sign.

Comment: What I mean `10` itself 2'complement then -ve?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You can get the two's complement notation of both negative and positive numbers like this `format(-2 % (1 << 32), "032b")`

Comment: @thefourtheye: I'd use a bitmask: `format(-2 & ((1 << 32) - 1), "032b")`

Comment: There's a small step missing in your explanation (and in the other answer as well). The fact that `bool` subclasses `int` doesn't imply that `~True` must be `-2`. The fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int` that overrides *only* `&`, `|` and `^` does, which might not be obvious.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Ah, I'll have to take that back; `bool` does override those methods, to make sure to call `super(bool, self).__<operator>__(other)` if either `self` or `other` is not a `bool` instance.

Comment: @Bakuriu: But I think it hardly matters here; `__invert__` is not implemented which is what *would* matter here.

Answer (score 4):

`~True == -2` is **not surprising if** `True` means `1` **and** `~` means *bitwise inversion*...

...**provided that**

- `True` can be treated as an integer and
- integers are represented in [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

---

Edits:

- fixed the mixing between integer representation and bitwise inversion operator
- applied another polishing (the shorter the message, the more work needed)

Comment: `~` does not mean "2s complement". `~` means "Bitwise Inversion"

Comment: The phrase "Ones' complement" doesn't really refer to an operation, as much as it refers to a system of storing integers in bits. A system that isn't actually used in a computer system.