# Clearing least significant bit

Tags: c, bit

## Question

How would I change the least significant bit to 0 without affecting the rest of the value, for example: `0xffffffff` , for example in C or Python? I am not a mathematical genius, so for me it's a hassle to find out how to achieve this.

## Solution

```
n = 0 // clear this bit
0xffffffff &= ~(1U << n) = 0xfffffffe
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21881463/1673391) will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to clear the least significant bit:

```
int x = 0xffffffff;

...

/* clear least significant bit */
x &= ~1;
```

To set the LSB

```
int x = 0xffffffff;

...

/* set least significant bit */
x |= 1;
```

To change the LSB

```
int x = 0xffffffff;

...

/* change least significant bit */
x ^= 1;
```

If you want to extent that to set / clear / change bit `n`, change the `1` to `(1U<<n)`.

Comment: Thank you. `x &= ~(1U << n)` is the finest solution in my case. Because if I would use `x ^= 1U << n`, it'd only flip the bit. I need to be sure that it is clearing the bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
 unsigned x = (x>>1U)    
          x = (x<<1U)
```

This is easy to understand ....
example :
Let x = 10010101011

> step 1 : x = **0** 1001010101 **// x>>1**
>   step 2 : x = 1001010101 **0**  **// x<<1**

**compare** :

> 10010101011
>   10010101010

Another method can be unsigned x = `x & 0Xfffffffe` which is equal to `11111111111111111111111111111110` i.e 31 bits 1 to keep bit 31 to 1 as it occours in x .

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Using bitwise `NOT` operator `~0` evaluates to all bits set to `1`. Assign this to an `unsigned int` variable and shift it left by 1 bit so that all bits are `1` except the least significant bit. The use bitwise `AND` operator `&` on `x` to toggle the least significant bit.

```
unsigned int x = 0xffffffff;
unsigned int y = 0;
x = x & (~0 << 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dig into bit ops, just do `i = (i / 2) * 2;`. This will clear bit 0 (why?).

Comment: this is exactly what you wanted to know, without any attempt to become a mathematical genius ;)

Comment: That's true, thanks! But it is more difficult to understand why this works than why the other answers work in my opinion. And this is not mathematically explainable, but rather computer science related.

Comment: @maikovich it's because for any number, whether it's even or odd, if we multiply it by 2, it'll become an even number and even numbers don't have bit 0. E.g.: `4 = 0b100`, `6 = 0b110`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The C compiler can translate this to recommended `(i / 2U) * 2U` solution for unsigned numbers because of no need for `0xFF..FEu` logical AND constant operand which can't be directly encoded as assembly instruction immediate at some cores (e.g. some Cortex ARMs) or the `-Os` compiler option favour this solution.

In assembly language, this mathematical expression turns to only two instructions - logical shift right and logical shift left without carry.

Alternative mathematical explanation not using the binary representation shifted right and left is, that the `(i / 2U) * 2U` results in nearest lower even number (result is the `i` again or `i - 1U` if `i` is odd). This means that the odd element was only removed from the number which is the `1*2^0` -> the lsb in binary representation.