# Tilde (~) operator changes boolean into int: Python 3

Tags: python

```
is_bid_unique = (len(np.unique(bus.loc[:,'bid']))==len(bus.loc[:,'bid']))
```

My code above returns `False` when you call `is_bid_unique`, but returns `-1` when you call `~is_bid_unique`.  Why is this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Using `~` (bitwise not) on a boolean converts it into a number object. `False` becomes `0`, and `~0` is `-1` (i.e. `~00...00` is `11...11`). Do you mean to use the logical not operator, `not`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881362/why-does-true-result-in-2